# Acces to database as guest auditor at another university

Tags: license, databases

For my doctorate (economics) I absolutely need access to a scientific database. The problem is that my university unfortunately does not offer this database in its library.
The database access as well as single data from the database would be much too expensive for my university.
There is also no kind of agreement possible with another university that offers this database.

For this reason, I am considering enrolling as a guest PhD-student in a university that offers this database to all its members.
However, I am not sure if this would be in accordance with the licensing law.
So I would get the necessary data from the database in **University B** and use this data for my research at my **University A**.
Downloading the data from the database in **University B** is completely legal for guest PhD-students.
But I don't know if I can use this data for research at my **University A**.

Can anyone tell me if this would be legally okay?

Maybe someone has already been in a similar situation and can help me.

For a better legal classification: I am doing my doctorate in Germany.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Ask your library to get access and get your advisor to support your request.

Comment: I already did. They couldn't help me either.

Comment: Can you provide some insight on what that data is and the source?

Comment: I'm looking for company data. (Mergers and aquisitions; M&A). These data are in the "Thomson One Banker"-database.

Comment: First, go to a research librarian at your institution. Tell them of the situation. Ask them how to get access through University B, where they likely have contacts. Then it is up to the University B folks to determine if it is possible under their license agreement with the database, and what is needed to make it possible. Simply visiting may be sufficient.